# JQuery UI slider handle fade colors until clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a vertical slider using Jquery UI and I want to make it a little more obvious someone should click it.  To achieve this, I think I want it to change color until clicked for the first time.  I'm trying to figure out what element to change, but am failing.

I am trying:

```
$("secrets-slider.a").animate("background-color","orange",500).animate("background-color","red",500);
```

Then setting a timeout and calling the function again.  However, secret-slider.a doesn't seem to work to refer to the handle.  How might I do that?

Edit: Since I was asked for code, here it is(though I don't understand why it's needed since it's stock jquery UI)

http://jsfiddle.net/tdWdw/

Comment: Can you include all of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how you want the color change to happen, but here's one option:

http://jsfiddle.net/tdWdw/2

```
  $(function () {
      $("#slider-vertical").slider({
          orientation: "vertical",
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          value: 60,
          slide: function (event, ui) {
              $("#amount").val(ui.value);
              $('#slider-vertical a').css('background-color', 'gray');
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly right.  I don't know why I was referring to <a> as a class.  That was my stupid mistake.

Comment: We've all been there. Don't sweat it.